# Strange behaviour using android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I have strange behavior with `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line` while using
`MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.

The code I use is:

```java
contactId = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.contactId);
contactAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,readContacts());
contactId.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
contactId.setThreshold(1);
```

My layout file contains:

```xml
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/contactId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="To"
    android:layout_margin="3dip">
</MultiAutoCompleteTextView>
```

My Emulator show white background on `multiAutoCompleteTextView` with transparent 
`contactList` info in it.

Why am I having such strange behavior? I am using Android 2.2 for the development.

Comment: Upgrade your current Android 2.2 again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by updating my android version

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem. the content of `drop down` dose not show in an `android 2.2` device .
I had solve problem by change layout of `drop down`

**Change** :

```
android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line
```

**To** :

```
R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item
```